# How to add begin transaction and rollback transaction in preview sql script using FluentMigration?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, .net-core, fluent-migrator

I'm using FluentMigrator for my .Net project and I want to create a sql script to preview my modification when calling dotnet fm migrate command.

Unfortunately, we didn't have the "begin transaction" and "rollback transaction" in the preview script generated. We used to have these commands in the script some months ago based on our old files.

Could you please tell me if I miss something in the command line ?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Alex

```sh
dotnet fm migrate -p sqlserver2012 -a "mydll.dll" -c "Data Source=mydatasource" -o="Migrations/MigrationScript.sql" -V --preview
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to begin a transaction is this:

```
internal static void MigrateUp()
{
    var serviceProvider = CreateServices();

    // Put the database update into a scope to ensure
    // that all resources will be disposed.
    using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        // Instantiate the runner
        var runner = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMigrationRunner>();

        using(var runnerScope = runner.BeginScope())
        {
            try
            {
                runner.MigrateUp();
                runnerScope.Complete();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                runnerScope.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```